# Select approriate cell based on current time

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, vlookup

Have been scratching my head for the last hour now.

I have a timetable with time values in Column A and then activity on Column B

e.g.

```
 COLUMN A    |   COLUMN B 
0.3333333333       EAT
0.3715277778       SLEEP
0.4097222222       PRAY
0.4444444444       DO NOTHING
0.46875            .
0.5034722222       .
0.5416666667       .
0.5798611111
0.625
0.6666666667
```

What I want to do is excel to tell me what I should be doing now, and what I should be doing next.

---

I can get the current time like this: `=MOD(NOW(),1)`

I'm thinking I need to turn the value of `=MOD(NOW(),1)` into exactly one of the values in column A, then I can do a VLOOKUP to tell me what I need to be doing now/next (in Column B)

I've been playing with `MATCH`, `CHOOSE`, I have to use some nested `AND` to find out if the current time is before or after the times in Column A. But I just can't figure this one out.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried approximate return of `VLOOKUP`function? I.e. last parameter of `VLOOKUP` set to 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. That works for finding the time that is the closest match, but I want to be able to specifically select the time slot that we are in, and the time slot that will be next.

For example:

if time is after 0.3333333333 but before 0.3715277778 it should always match with 0.3333333333

Comment: The approximate match returns the next largest value that is less than your specific lookup value (in general case when you have sorted data). So for 0.37 search you would get 0.33 result even that 0.37 is closer to 0.371.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do it with a few simple steps.
First, as I understand in column A you have start time, then in column B you need end time, in cell B2 put =A3.
So you can have something like:

```
start       end       to-do
08:00:00    08:55:00  eat
08:55:00    09:50:00  go
09:50:00    10:40:00  something
10:40:00    11:15:00  .
11:15:00    12:05:00  .
12:05:00    13:00:00
13:00:00    13:55:00
13:55:00    15:00:00
15:00:00    16:00:00
16:00:00
```

It's very easy from there. 
Add one column on your left (for vlookup purpose). Let's say you have current time in cell G2. Then in your new column A in cell A2 put a formula:

```
=AND($G$2>=B2;$G$2<C2)
```

to check if your current time is in the time range you have in your start and end.
If your current time is 11:45 then you should have something like this:

```
        start       end       to-do
FALSE   08:00:00    08:55:00  eat
FALSE   08:55:00    09:50:00  go
FALSE   09:50:00    10:40:00  something
FALSE   10:40:00    11:15:00  .
TRUE    11:15:00    12:05:00  .
FALSE   12:05:00    13:00:00
FALSE   13:00:00    13:55:00
FALSE   13:55:00    15:00:00
FALSE   15:00:00    16:00:00
FALSE   16:00:00
```

then all you need to do is vlookup where TURE is.

EDIT: to check what you should do next you need vlookup nested in vlookup. First instead using vlookup to find what value is in column to-do you need to vlookup value in the column end (12:05:00). Then this value can be set as value to look up in range columns start:to-do.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was great.